# A connection is established and does not fill the database because of this mySQL error

Tags: mysql

WARNING: MYSQL_OPT_RECONNECT is deprecated and will be removed in a future version
I created a server on the host and connect to the database writes an error

I used different versions of the plugin for the server (connecting to the database does not help). Previously, everything worked, I can't figure out what the error is very strange

Comment: Welcome to SO, you did not share much info. Probably you upgraded MySQL before this happened? From/To which version was this upgrade?  Please share all relevant info, which makes we can stop **guessing**  (and, of course, do some research before asking, than you could have found the other question, ans could have asked a better question)